# reference maven shade plugin 3.3.1-SNAPSHOT in pom

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

According to the site

https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-shade-plugin-LATEST/shade-mojo.html

the latest version of the maven shade plugin is `3.3.1-SNAPSHOT` and exists since 2021-07-14.

To reference the earlier version `3.3.0-SNAPSHOT`, I used the following reference in the pom

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My question how to reference `3.3.1-SNAPSHOT` in the pom.
When running `mvn install` I am getting the following error:

`ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT:shade ([...]) on project [...]: Execution [...] of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT:shade failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:3.3.1-20220317.155034-43 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.7.32 from/to maven-snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/): transfer failed for https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/slf4j-api-1.7.32.pom: Unknown host repository.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution -> [Help 1]`

So is the problem with slf4j? Can I resolve this somehow?

Thank you!

PS: the reason why i would like to try out the latest version is because I am getting the following errors when running `mvn install`:

with maven-shade-plugin `3.2.4`:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (owlex) on project owl: Error creating shaded jar: Unsupported class file major version 61 -> [Help 1]`

with maven-shade-plugin `3.3.0-SNAPSHOT`:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:shade (owlex) on project owl: Error creating shaded jar: Records requires ASM8 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Is there particular reason why you like to use a SNAPSHOT version ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes: all previous versions of the maven plugin do not support all Java 17 features.

Comment: In which way? What does not work?

Comment: @khmarbaise specifically `record`s does not work. (but instanceof pattern works). give me 5 minutes, I will regenerate the error message and add it to the question.

Comment: Also please a full example which shows the problem..

Comment: @khmarbaise i have added the errors in the question. i started looked into a version later than `3.2.4` because that version gave me `Unsupported class file major version 61`

Comment: Can you make an example project please on Github or alike?...

Comment: yes, I will do so in the evening. Btw, I am using latest Fedora linux. Other question: is there a project on github that uses java 17, records, and the shade plugin that you know of?

Comment: Yes I know a project of https://github.com/khmarbaise/jacem

Comment: the build fails on my machine with the following trace: https://pastebin.com/P1D2xLwU

Comment: example project created and also fails using github actions: https://github.com/datahaki/java/runs/5597835505?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: The parts you have posted shown rule failures with maven-enforcer-plugin but you have cut the logs please post a full output of the logs...If I try to compile your example project (apart from having strange configuration; repository in Github package etc.) most important it references a version of tenso 1.0.2 which does not even exist ...so I can't try to compile the code...furthermore using very old libs JUnit 3 based unit Tests etc. is a different story...

Comment: @khmarbaise the link to github (that i sent last) shows the complete log of the github workflow (that can serve as a neutral ground since it runs in their virtual machine). The workflow simply consist of `mvn install`. The error is exactly what i am getting on my machine, namely `Records requires ASM8`. Note that the branch that the link points to and into which i made the experimental commit is `v031`. (PS: That the main branch builds can be seen by the green checkmark, i.e. the dependencies in the main branch are fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend to use the most recent version of maven-shade-plugin version 3.3.0 which has been released.

This will handle JDK 17 correctly.

https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@maven.apache.org/msg01066.html

Comment: please give me some time to verify...

Comment: just tested `3.3.0` - works with `record`s - yey!